# cakephp set:extract array generated by find joins

Tags: arrays, cakephp, extract

I have cakephp 2.8 project, I have an array returned by `Model->find('all',array('joins'))` which is something like this

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Result' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'student_id' => '1',
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'fullname' => 'Alam'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Result' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'student_id' => '11',
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'fullname' => 'Student 1'
    )
)
);
```

I want this array as below

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'student_id' => '1',
        'fullname' => 'Alam'
),
(int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'student_id' => '11',
        'fullname' => 'Student 1'
)
);
```

I tried `Set::extract('/Result/.');` , `Set::extract('/Result/User/.');` and other variations but I am not getting desired result.
I know I can do it by foreach loop but I want if it can be done by some builtin php or cakephp function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to use only one function, but, maybe this will do the trick for you:

```
$t = Hash::mergeDiff(
            Hash::extract($inputArray, '{n}.Result'),
            Hash::extract($inputArray, '{n}.User')
            );

debug($t);
```